# Is the given subset a subspace $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

This question appears in the exercise section of Jim Hefferon's Linear Algebra book. The question had two subsets of $\mathbb{R}^2$ one of them is:

$W_1 = \{ (1,0)^T + (x,0)^T \,\,| \,x \in \mathbb{R}\,\}$

The solution sets says that both the subsets are not subspaces. The question I had was how come $W_1$ is not a subspace.

My explanation is as follows:

Assume $a_1 = (x_1 + 1,0)^T,\, a_2 = (x_2 + 1,0)^T \in W_1 \,\, and \,\, r_1,r_2 \in \mathbb R $
then, 
$\, r_1a_1 = (r_1(x_1 + 1),0)^T = (r_1x_1 + r_1 - 1  ,0)^T +(1,0)^T $ and
$ r_2a_2 = (r_2(x_2 + 1),0)^T = (r_2x_2 + r_2 - 1 ,0)^T +(1,0)^T $

 $\therefore r_1a_1,r_2a_2 \in W_1, since \,\, r_1x_1 + r_1 - 1,\, r_2x_2 + r_2 - 1 \in \mathbb R $ 
$\therefore r_1a_1 + r_2a_2 = ((r_1x_1 + r_1 + r_2x_2 + r_2 - 1)  ,0)^T +(1,0)^T $

$\therefore r_1a_1 + r_2a_2 \in W_1 $

Doesn't this prove that $W_1$ is subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$?
So I just want to understand if my proof is correct.

Comment: $W_1$ is a subspace and your argument is correct.

Comment: It looks to me like it's the $x$-axis and it's a subspace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The set as it is defined is simply the set of all multiples of $(1,0)$

which is of course a subspace!

It is just the line $y=0$, there is no need for any further

explanation.